# Finding an exact match of an inner text using XPath

Tags: xpath

What XPath syntax can I use to find an anchor tag where the inner text is "abc". The closest I can get to this is:

```
SelectSingleNode(".//a[starts-with(., \"abc\")]");
```

I couldn't find any "equals" function to use.

Comment: You are looking for the node name whose content (between tags) is "abc"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
SelectSingleNode("//a[.='abc']");
```

`//` ususally means you intend to search the whole tree, why would you add `.` before that?

Comment: From the spec: "A location step of `.` is short for `self::node()`. This is particularly useful in conjunction with `//`. For example, the location path `.//para` is short for `self::node()/descendant-or-self::node()/child::para`
and so will select all `para` descendant elements of the context node."

Comment: Yes, I know - but thanks for pointing it out so clearly. It's just that I am not sure whether the OP actually wanted to write simply `"//"`.